# Creating Array inside extension method TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an extension method using typeScript, in that extension method I wanted to create a static variable or you can say a normal variable.
I had called the ServiceCollector method 3 times by sending the data or object to it and trying to store here in an object of array.
here my code is

```
import { Employee } from "./Employee.model";

let datafetcher: Employee[] = [];

declare global {
  interface Object {
    ServiceCollector(data): any[];
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'ServiceCollector', {
  value: function(data) {
    datafetcher.push(data);
    console.log(datafetcher);
    return "done";
  },
  enumerable: false
});
```

the array `datafetcher` is storing the value but the problem is that it overrides all the previous data by the latest.

```
Array : 0: {code: 101, FirstName: "Aditya"}

/*Adding another value */
Array : 0: {code: 102, FirstName: "Aryan"}
Array : 1: {code: 102, FirstName: "Aryan"}

/*Adding another value */
Array : 0: {code: 103, FirstName: "Kundan"}
Array : 1: {code: 103, FirstName: "Kundan"}
Array : 2: {code: 103, FirstName: "Kundan"}
```

I tried my brain into it but not able to figure why I am getting such kind of behavior.
**This is how I am calling the ServiceCollector method**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './Employee.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  EmployeeObject: Employee = {};
  ParentObject: Object = {};

  submit1() {
    this.EmployeeObject.code = 102;
    this.EmployeeObject.FirstName = 'Aryan Toke';
    console.log("Submit 1", this.EmployeeObject);
    this.ParentObject.ServiceCollector(this.EmployeeObject);
  }

  submit2() {
    this.EmployeeObject.code = 103;
    this.EmployeeObject.FirstName = 'Kundan Toke';
    console.log("Submit 2", this.EmployeeObject);
    this.ParentObject.ServiceCollector(this.EmployeeObject);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.EmployeeObject.code = 101;
    this.EmployeeObject.FirstName = 'Aditya Toke';
    console.log("ngoninit", this.EmployeeObject);
    this.ParentObject.ServiceCollector(this.EmployeeObject);
  }

}
```

on click of button `submit1()` and `submit2()` methods are going to get called

Comment: I suspend it's the problem on how you use it. Can you post that part too?

Comment: ok will edit provide the code

Answer (score 0):

The service (that store the data) my-service.ts

```
import { Employee } from "./Employee.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  myStoreArray: Employee[] = [];

  saveData(data:Employee){
    this.myStoreArray.push(data);
    console.log("Data saved "+JSON.stringify(data));
  }

}
```

In the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './Employee.model';
import { MyService } from 'where you like to put you service ./my-service.ts';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private mySvc: MyService) { }

  submit1() {
    let newEmployee: Employee = {
      code: 102,
      FirstName: 'Aryan Toke'
    }
    console.log("Submit 1", newEmployee);
    this.mySvc.saveData(newEmployee);
  }
  submit2() {
    let newEmployee: Employee = {
      code: 103,
      FirstName: 'Kundan Toke'
    }
    console.log("Submit 2", newEmployee);
    this.mySvc.saveData(newEmployee);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let newEmployee: Employee = {
      code: 101,
      FirstName: 'Aditya Toke'
    }
    console.log("ngoninit", newEmployee);
    this.mySvc.saveData(newEmployee);
  }
}
```

Comment: bro i am not using service i just named my variable that way

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you are adding the same reference to EmployeeObject to the array each time, and mutating it to have the latest values.

If you instead create a new object when you pass data to the service everything will be fine

Eg:

```
this.ParentObject.ServiceCollector({code: X, FirstName: Y});
```

Also not that the code presented in Francesco's answer above is more idiomatic Typescript / Angular code, compared to creating a method using Object.defineProperty - I suggest you have a read about services here: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: but i am assigning new value to the object before pushing it in array, and i m not using service its just like my variable name

Comment: And its like i m creating variables when ever my data is coming thats the reason i created a one object and reassigning the value to it

Comment: In the code you give you are mutating the properties of the EmployeeObject variable. If you added a line like `this.EmployeeObject = {}` prior to assigning to it's properties then the code would work as you expect it to.